# Django Hello World

Tags: python, django

Закачал Django, установил. `import django` нормально интерпритируется.
Зашел сделал проект `mysite` и в нем приложение `polls`.

Помогите хотя бы сделать `hello world`. В какой файл прописывать и как дальше быть?
Искал, но мануалов нет.

Comment: https://www.djangoproject.com/start/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/

Answer (score 8):

У Django отличная документация, и туториал там тоже есть: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 3):

плохо искал. Я делал по этому учебнику http://djbook.ru/rel1.5/ только для другой версии. всё работает, хорошо описано.